# Button setClickSelector is not working in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I added a button on a panel. But after adding a button on panel it's `setClickSelector` is not working.

// Creating panel Here//

```
CCPanel* panel_coinBooster = CCPanel::create();
    panel_coinBooster->setPosition(ccp(BullMenu1::x/4, BullMenu1::y/6));
    panel_coinBooster->setBackgroundNode(CCSprite::create("coin_boosterBG.png"));
    addChild(panel_coinBooster,10);
```

// Creating Button Here and adding it on a panel //

```
CCButton* button = CCButton::create("use_Btn.png", "use_ButtonTouch.png","use_Btn.png");

button->setPosition(BullMenu1::x/1.5f,BullMenu1::y/1.9f);
button->setClickSelector(this,click_selector(Classname::scoreBoosterUsed));

panel_coinBooster->addChild(useButton_score ,10);

void PowerLayer::scoreBoosted()
{


}
```

Comment: i figured it out. we have to set  setClickSelector() on panel also

Answer (score 0):

Selector and function names are different, if you want `scoreBoosted` to be executed use that function in setClickSelector. Also, do you really have a class named `Classname`?